# Scrolling issues with the navigation bar, body, and footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

### The issue

I'm experiencing a scrolling issue with my Navigation Bar, Body, and Footer when using Bootstrap 4. Everything seems to work great on the desktop viewport. The problem lies when I shrink the viewport. The body doesn't stay down and it becomes impossible to scroll when the body is between the navbar and the footer

I'm also unsure as to why the following code is in my navbar:

```
<div style="padding-block-end: 200px;">
  {{> navbar}}
</div>
```

The start of my content is partly hidden by the navigation bar as well.

```css
:root {
  --navbar-bg-color: hsl(0, 0%, 15%);
  --navbar-text-color: hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
  --navbar-text-color-focus: white;
  --navbar-bg-contrast: hsl(0, 0%, 25%);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding-left: 1.4rem;
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#navbar {
  --navbar-height: 64px;
  position: fixed;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  background-color: var(--navbar-bg-color);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-item {
  margin: 0.4em;
  width: 100%;
}

.home-link,
.navbar-link {
  color: var(--navbar-text-color);
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  align-items: center;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.home-link:focus,
.home-link:hover {
  color: var(--navbar-text-color-focus);
}

.navbar-link {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.navbar-link:focus,
.navbar-link:hover {
  color: var(--navbar-text-color-focus);
  background-color: var(--navbar-bg-contrast);
}

.navbar-logo {
  background-color: var(--navbar-text-color-focus);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--navbar-text-color);
}

.navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar,
.navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar {
  background-color: var(--navbar-text-color-focus);
}

#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:first-child,
#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30px;
}

#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--navbar-height);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, visibility 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#navbar.opened .navbar-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.navbar-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--navbar-bg-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#navbar.opened .navbar-links {
  padding: 1em;
  max-height: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  #navbar .navbar-menu,
  #navbar.opened .navbar-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    position: static;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #navbar .navbar-links,
  #navbar.opened .navbar-links {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: static;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    max-height: max-content;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #navbar .navbar-link:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
body {
  background: rgb(30, 30, 40);
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  background-image: url("/public/img/5a2c61199c0fa1.0890734315128578816392.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

form {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.feedback-input {
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 40);
  // background:transparent;
  border: 2px solid #7dabdb;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  padding: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
}

.feedback-input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #7dabdb;
}

textarea {
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150%;
  resize: vertical;
}

[type="submit"] {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background: #7dabdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #7dabdb;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.footer {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(0, 0%, 15%), hsl(0, 0%, 15%)), url("http://andreeabunget.co.uk/Img/footer.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.second2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.second h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.second h4::after {
  content: '';
  background: #66c83d;
  width: 20%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 40%;
}

.second li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.second a,
.second2 a {
  color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.second a:hover,
.second2 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgb(50, 129, 175);
  text-decoration: none
}

.third {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .first {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .first h4::after {
    left: 40%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .third {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .third h4::after {
    left: 40% !important;
  }
}

.margin {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<header id="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar-container container navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <a href="/" class="home-link">
      <div class="navbar-logo"></div>
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" aria-label="Open navigation menu">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-menu">
      <ul class="navbar-links">
        <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/">home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/">...</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/">...</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/">...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- Main Body -->
<div class="container form-group">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sendmail">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" required="required" />
    <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
    <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Message" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" action="sendmail" />
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="second2">
            <a href="https://codepen.io/AndreeaBunget" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-codepen fa-2x margin"></i></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-github fa-2x margin"></i></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x margin"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCX674BUbomzBCakbb75lhfA?view_as=subscriber" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x margin"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this happens because the height of the `form` is smaller than the height of your screen.

you can add `min-height: 100vh;` to make sure the content is always visible.
also, you can use flexbox to set the elements wherever you want. it's easier and faster to develop.

Here is your code with some edits:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

:root {
  --navbar-bg-color: hsl(0, 0%, 15%);
  --navbar-text-color: hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
  --navbar-text-color-focus: white;
  --navbar-bg-contrast: hsl(0, 0%, 25%);
}

body {
  background: rgb(30, 30, 40);
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  background-image: url("/public/img/5a2c61199c0fa1.0890734315128578816392.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding-left: 1.4rem;
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
}







/* Navbar Style */

#navbar {
  --navbar-height: 64px;
  position: fixed;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  background-color: var(--navbar-bg-color);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-item {
  margin: 0.4em;
  width: 100%;
}
.home-link,
.navbar-link {
  color: var(--navbar-text-color);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  align-items: center;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.home-link:focus,
.home-link:hover {
  color: var(--navbar-text-color-focus);
}
.navbar-link {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.navbar-link:focus,
.navbar-link:hover {
  color: var(--navbar-text-color-focus);
  background-color: var(--navbar-bg-contrast);
}
.navbar-logo {
  background-color: var(--navbar-text-color-focus);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out,
    opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--navbar-text-color);
}
.navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar,
.navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar {
  background-color: var(--navbar-text-color-focus);
}
#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:first-child,
#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30px;
}
#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
#navbar.opened .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.navbar-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--navbar-height);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, visibility 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#navbar.opened .navbar-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.navbar-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--navbar-bg-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#navbar.opened .navbar-links {
  padding: 1em;
  max-height: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  #navbar .navbar-menu,
  #navbar.opened .navbar-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    position: static;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #navbar .navbar-links,
  #navbar.opened .navbar-links {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: static;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    max-height: max-content;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #navbar .navbar-link:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}






/* Content Style */
.content {
  margin-top:100px;
  min-height: 100vh; /* To make the user able to see the content  */
}
.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
form {
  max-width: 500px;
}
.feedback-input {
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 40);
  border: 2px solid #7dabdb;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  padding: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
}
.feedback-input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #7dabdb;
}
textarea {
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150%;
  resize: vertical;
}
[type="submit"] {
  font-family: "Montserrat", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background: #7dabdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #7dabdb;
}








/* Footer Styles */

.footer {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(0, 0%, 15%), hsl(0, 0%, 15%)),
    url("http://andreeabunget.co.uk/Img/footer.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  margin:20px 0 0;
  padding:20px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}

.second2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.second h4 {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.second h4::after {
  content: "";
  background: #66c83d;
  width: 20%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 40%;
}
.second li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.second a, .second2 a {
  color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.second a:hover, .second2 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgb(50, 129, 175);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.third {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}
.margin {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .first {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .first h4::after {
    left: 40%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .third {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .third h4::after {
    left: 40% !important;
  }
}
```

and here is the HTML Code:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<header id="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar-container navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <a href="/" class="home-link">
      <div class="navbar-logo"></div>
      Brand
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" aria-label="Open navigation menu">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-menu">
      <ul class="navbar-links">
        <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/">home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/">About</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- Content -->
<div class="container form-group content">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sendmail">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" required="required" />
    <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
    <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Message" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" action="sendmail" />
  </form>
</div>

<!-- footer -->
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="second2">

            <a href="" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-github fa-2x margin"></i></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x margin"></i></a>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
```

here's the code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ElalfiWeb/pen/PoGQrZq) too.

Comment: you fixed my problem, thank you very much for taking the time to correct me !!

Comment: Thanks, Sameh, Flexbox is amazing.